# Python XML Random assignment

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to assign a random value to XML password tag.

Example of the XML file.

```
<database>
 <group>
   <entry>
    <username>root</username>
    <password>XXXXXX</password>
   </entry>
   <entry>
    <username>root</username>
    <password>YYYYY</password>
   </entry>
 </group>
</database>
```

This my current python code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import random
import string

random = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation) for n in range(10)])

tree = ET.ElementTree(file='test2.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for admin in root.findall("./group/entry/[username='root']"):
    password = admin.find('password').text = random
    print(password)
```

I'm getting the same random value assigned. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the generation of a random value into the loop in order to generate a new value each time.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import random
import string

tree = ET.ElementTree(file='test2.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

for admin in root.findall("./group/entry/[username='root']"):
    rand = ''.join([random.choice(chars) for n in range(10)])
    password = admin.find('password').text = rand
    print(password)
```

Also, when naming your variable `random` you are overriding the package `random` imported, it's bad practice, consider changing your variable name to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You assigned the first random value to the `random` variable and then never changed its value.

In order to achieve what you want you need to calculate the random value within the loop:

```
for admin in root.findall("./group/entry/[username='root']"):
    password = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation) for n in range(10)])
    print(password)
```

On a side note: you should avoid [shadowing standard library modules](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap) when naming your variables.